# How to create Linq2Sql query, calculating aggregates?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to create Linq2SQL query, that will be translated to this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as totalCount ,
 SUM(v.field1) AS totalfield1,
....
 SUM(v.<fieldN>) AS total<fieldN>
FROM    [dbo].[SomeTable] v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
var query = from p in SalesOrderDetails 
         group p by p.ProductID into g
          select  new
          {id =  g.Key, Count = g.Count(), Sum = g.Sum(p => p.OrderQty)};   

Console.Write(query);
```

but your solution of using fake key and then enumerating seems much better.

```
var query = from p in SalesOrderDetails 
         group p by p.ProductID into g
        select  new
  {id =  g.Key, FalseKey = 1, Count = g.Count(), Sum = g.Sum(p => p.OrderQty) };

//Console.Write(query);
var result = from q in query
                  group q by q.FalseKey into c
                  select new { summation = c.Sum(q => q.Sum)};

Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found soluthion with DataObjects.NET

```
var query =  
    from product in Query.All<Product>()
    where product.ProductName.Contains("a")
    select new {Product = product, FakeKey = 0} into i
    group i.Product.UnitPrice by i.FakeKey into g
    select new { Count = g.Count(), Price = g.Sum() };

  var result = query.AsEnumerable().Single();
```

SQL:

```
SELECT Count_big(*)         AS [column1], 
       SUM([a].[UnitPrice]) AS [column2] 
FROM   (SELECT [b].[ProductId], 
               [b].[TypeId], 
               [b].[ProductName], 
               [b].[Seller], 
               [b].[Category.Id], 
               [b].[ProductType], 
               [b].[UnitPrice], 
               [b].[UnitsInStock], 
               [b].[UnitsOnOrder], 
               [b].[ReorderLevel], 
               [b].[QuantityPerUnit], 
               0 AS [column] 
        FROM   [dbo].[Products] [b] 
        WHERE  ( [b].[ProductName] LIKE '%a%' )) [a] 
GROUP  BY [a].[column];
```